# Rust: load values from raw pointers

Tags: pointers, rust

I'm actually trying to understand how data are stored and loaded using pointers with rust, but when I run this code:

```rs
#[cfg(test)]
mod tests{
    fn get_pointer<T>(a:T) -> *const i32{
        ptr::addr_of!(a)
    }

    #[test]
    fn f(){
        unsafe {
            let a = 5;
            let pointer = get_pointer(a);
            let encoded = bincode::serialize(&(pointer as usize)).unwrap();
            let decoded = bincode::deserialize::<usize>(&encoded[..]).unwrap() as *const i32;
            let b = std::ptr::read(decoded);
            assert_eq!(a, b);
        }
    }
}
```

The value stored in `b` become `0` instead of `5`, and I cannot figure out why this happens and how to solve this.

I think that the problem occurs because the value of a is dropped after the function returns the pointer but I'm not sure if that's right

Comment: `let pointer = (&a) as *const _;`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I think that the problem occurs because the value of a is dropped after the function returns the pointer but I'm not sure if that's right

Well yes, pretty much. The locals of a function only live for the extent of that function (which is why rustc will refuse compiling if you try to return a *reference* to function-local data), so `get_pointer` returns a dangling pointer, serializing and deserializing the pointer does quite literally nothing, and the `ptr::read` is UB:

> ### Safety
>
> Behavior is undefined if any of the following conditions are violated:
>
> - src must be valid for reads.
> - src must be properly aligned. Use read_unaligned if this is not the case.
> - **src must point to a properly initialized value of type T.**

Running the program using miri unambiguously flags the issue:

```
error: Undefined Behavior: pointer to alloc1416 was dereferenced after this allocation got freed
   --> /playground/.rustup/toolchains/nightly-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/src/rust/library/core/src/ptr/mod.rs:703:9
    |
703 |         copy_nonoverlapping(src, tmp.as_mut_ptr(), 1);
    |         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ pointer to alloc1416 was dereferenced after this allocation got freed
    |
    = help: this indicates a bug in the program: it performed an invalid operation, and caused Undefined Behavior
    = help: see https://doc.rust-lang.org/nightly/reference/behavior-considered-undefined.html for further information
            
    = note: inside `std::ptr::read::<i32>` at /playground/.rustup/toolchains/nightly-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/src/rust/library/core/src/ptr/mod.rs:703:9
note: inside `main` at src/main.rs:12:17
   --> src/main.rs:12:17
    |
12  |         let b = ptr::read(decoded);
    |                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

> I'm actually trying to understand how data are stored and loaded using pointers with rust

Doing it that way is a terrible idea, you're stepping off way into UB land and that means *all bets are off*, what you observe (to the extent that you can observe anything) has no relations to defined semantics.